# Sharing Ioc and session between web api and mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api

I am in the process of adding web api 2 to an existing MVC 5 app.

We are using Unity and NHibernate session per. request. 
We have created a UnityControllerFactory based on DefaultControllerFactory. And the UnityControllerFactory is set in Application_Start like this:

_controllerFactory = new UnityControllerFactory(_container);
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(_controllerFactory);

This is not working for the web api, guess that we need to implement a unity resolver based on the interface [IDependencyResolver](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

Is there a way to use the same container for ApiController and Controller?

Comment: Do you mean the same container *instance* or the same container *configuration*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've done something similar with Autofac and Ninject before, not sure what the actual syntax would be for Unity but you would need something along the lines of this in your `Application_Start`:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
RegisterDependencies(container);

// Wire unity container with ASP.NET MVC
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new UnityControllerFactory(container));

// Wire unity container with Web Api
httpConfig.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

Comment: I tried the same, and it didn't work, or I did it? After 2 hours I found out that the constructor was protected )-: sometimes intellisense is not a blessing.